# Options are empty in a second selectlist form field after selection an option in the first selectlist (Mechanize and Ruby)

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am using Mechanize to get a page with a form.  The form has two fields that are selectlists.  The second selectlist has no options as a default until the user has selected an option from the first selectlist.  I am able to select an option from the first selectlist:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/')
form = page.forms.first

a = form.field("customBicycleSearch$ddnBikeSearchMake")
a.options[1].click
```

However, after that, I print the second selectlist's options but I get an empty array:

```
model = form.field("customBicycleSearch$ddnBikeSearchModel")
pp model.options
```

I am thinking this is because it is still parsing HTML from the initial pageload and isn't parsing HTML returned after the selectlist option was selected..... How can I access the second selectlist's options?

Comment: its hard to try unless you provide the actual page or its contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
page = agent.get('http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/')
```

do this

```
page = agent.get('http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchlisting.aspx?make=1081&model=67286&year=2012')
```

You can also use just the 'make'

```
  page = agent.get('http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchlisting.aspx?make=1081')
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I needed.  I was curious though, how did you decipher the URL pattern?  I tried using my browser's network inspector via an online tutorial but was unsuccessful...

Comment: You can use Chrome's developer tools or Firefox or FF plugin like Tamperdata.

Answer (score 0):

> However, after that, I print the second selectlist's options but I get
>   an empty array:
>
> I am thinking this is because it is still parsing HTML from the
>   initial pageload and isn't parsing HTML returned after the selectlist
>   option was selected.

The second select is probably populated by javascript.  javascript can be used to listen for events on an html page such as selecting something, or changing the focus to another html element.  When one of those events is triggered, a js program can then add elements to the page, like `<option>`'s.

> How can I access the second selectlist's options?

Not with mechanize.  You will need to use something that can execute javascript, like selenium:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

...and you will need to know some javascript.

Comment: It's an ajax request. Mechanize can do that, you just need to figure it out. The fact that it's asp makes it harder, and selenium might be an easier way to go, but I would still probably stick with mechanize (if it were me.)